# How to sort in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, case-sensitive

If I have an array like this:

```
var tab = ['1185 Design','3 D Exhibits','44Doors', '4Concepts','ABC Data','acceleration'];
```

And I want to sort it so that small letter `'a'` element comes before capital letter `'A'` element.

Comment: please add some code you tried and the wanted result.

Comment: Please look at some helpful tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - asking a good question improves your chances of getting an answer. But it is also equally important that you search first and do some research before posting your question. Also include what you have tried and indicate the problem(s) you are experiencing.

Comment: Pardon me I am new to coding

Comment: @user3555971: is your problem solved?, what is the result you need?

Comment: items which has the first letter starting with a-z should come before A-Z

Comment: @user3555971 and where should numbers come?

Comment: so does a word starting `aB` come before or after `Ab`? Your sorting rules are not very well defined at present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`Array#sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** method with **[`String#localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)**

```js
var tab = ['1185 Design', '3 D Exhibits', 'nb', 'N', 'cd', '44Doors', '4Concepts', 'ABC Data', 'acceleration'];

tab.sort(function(a, b) {
  return sortFn(a, b);
});

function sortFn(a, b) {
  // if both are equal return 0
  if (a == b) return 0;
  // if first characters are equal call the same function with remaining (recursion)
  if (a.charAt(0) == b.charAt(0)) return sortFn(a.slice(1), b.slice(1))
  // check lowercase or uppercase based on that return value
  if (/^[a-z]/.test(a.charAt(0)) && /^[A-Z]/.test(b.charAt(0))) return -1;
  if (/^[a-z]/.test(b.charAt(0)) && /^[A-Z]/.test(a.charAt(0))) return 1;
  // otherwise ude normal compare function
  return a.localeCompare(b);
}

console.log(tab);
```

---

**UPDATE :** In case if you want to sort with alphabetical order and small letter should have higher precedence only if they are equal then do something like.

```js
var tab = ['1185 Design', '3 D Exhibits', 'nb', 'N', 'cd', '44Doors', '4Concepts', 'ABC Data', 'acceleration'];

tab.sort(function(a, b) {
  return sortFn(a, b);
});

function sortFn(a, b) {
  // if both are equal return 0
  if (a == b) return 0;
  // if first characters are equal call the same function with remaining (recursion)
  if (a.charAt(0) == b.charAt(0)) return sortFn(a.slice(1), b.slice(1))
  // check lowercase or uppercasebased on that return value in case the letters are equal 
  if (a.charAt(0).toLowerCase() == b.charAt(0).toLowerCase()) {
    if (/^[a-z]/.test(a.charAt(0)) && /^[A-Z]/.test(b.charAt(0))) return -1;
    if (/^[a-z]/.test(b.charAt(0)) && /^[A-Z]/.test(a.charAt(0))) return 1;
  }
  // otherwise ude normal compare function
  return a.localeCompare(b);
}


console.log(tab);
```

Comment: Here is the code snippet. 

 var optionTexts = [];
$(".options li").each(function() { optionTexts.push($(this).text()) });
         
      
         console.log('=========');

          optionTexts.sort(function(a,b){
                        
              
            return b.localeCompare(a);
              
              
                    }
                   );
          
    console.log('sorted '+optionTexts); The above solution is not working properly for me.

Comment: @user3555971 share the `optionTexts` values

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for your reply, Can it be sorted like this acceleration next ABC Data , then small letter b items then captial letter B items grouped together.

Comment: Thanks a lot man :) where is the starting point where I can learn these functions. do you recommend any courses ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map) with a reversion of case.

```js
// the array to be sorted
var list = ['1185 Design', '3 D Exhibits', '44Doors', '4Concepts', 'ABC Data', 'acceleration'];

// temporary array holds objects with position and sort-value
var mapped = list.map(function (el, i) {
    return { index: i, value: el.split('').map(function (a) {
        var b = a.toUpperCase();
        return a === b ? a.toLowerCase(): b;
    }).join('')};
});

// sorting the mapped array containing the reduced values
mapped.sort(function (a, b) {
    return +(a.value > b.value) || +(a.value === b.value) - 1;
});

// container for the resulting order
var result = mapped.map(function (el) {
    return list[el.index];
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution.